# Function isn't executed when called. No debug error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I open the Google Sheet, it calls my "onOpen" function.
Even though I have a call for the function "ShowPGP" in my "onOpen" function, when I refresh the page, it doesn't seem to be running the "ShowPGP" function.
I'm not getting any errors when I run the script itself. 
When I run the script by itself, it does exactly what it's supposed to.

```
function onOpen() {
createMenus();
sortSheets();
ShowPGP();
}

function ShowPGP() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var PGPBlueColor = "#5b95f9"; 
for(var i =0; i<sheets.length; i++){
var color = sheets[i].getTabColor();
if(color == PGPBlueColor){
    if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()) {
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
  }
}
for(var i =0; i<sheets.length; i++){
var color = sheets[i].getTabColor();
 if(color != PGPBlueColor){
   if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()) {
    doNull();
   }
       else { 
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
       }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if you move ShowPGP() above the other two function calls? It could be crashing in one of those. Have you checked the execution transcript as well as the Log Viewer?

Comment: Actually I don't understand your script, you show sheets that are hidden with tab color PGPBlueColor then hide all sheets that are tab color PGPBlueColor.  Why not just hide all sheets with that tab color?  And what is doNull(), why even have that there?  if( !sheets[i].isSheetHidden() ) sheets[i].hideSheet();

Comment: Look at the actual execution logs for errors in your script's Stackdriver logs. Most probably you do something that a simple trigger cannot do.

Comment: The code isn't a [mcve] as `createMenus()` and `sortSheets()` are missing. Have you already reviewed "My Executions" on https://script.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Simple triggers like onOpen run with limited permissions. One of your functions is most likely attempting to do something which is outside the scope of those permissions.

See the restrictions documented here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions

And consult the My Executions section of https://script.google.com for additional details.